# Vue i18n translations in tag not changing by button to change language

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have few components with translations e.g:

```
<i18n>
  en:
    "Przykładowy tekst": "Example text"
</i18n>

<template>
<div>
    {{ $t('Przykładowy tekst') }}
</div>
</template>
```

In another component I have button to change language with method:

```
changeLanguage({ target: { value }}) {
    this.$i18n.locale = value
    this.$i18n.fallbackLocale = value
},
```

And I have file with setting `i18n`:

```
export const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'pl',
    fallbackLocale: 'pl',
    silentTranslationWarn: true,
    messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
})
```

I have file with repeated translations:
File `en.yml`:

```
"Usuń": "Remove"
"Anuluj": "Cancel"
```

Now when I change language using button, it's changing only text with translations from file `en.yml`. However, the text from the i18n tag from the component is not translated.

When I change `i18n` file to:

```
export const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    silentTranslationWarn: true,
    messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
})
```

and refresh the page, then then everything is translated correctly.